# Formal inverse of a matrix ressembling Fourier's matrix

Tags: matrices, fourier-analysis, inverse

What is the formal inverse of a square $N\times N$ matrix $A$ with entries $A_{ij}=a^{(i-1)(j-1)}$?

When $a$ is the $N$th root of unity (i.e. $a=\exp(2 \pi i/N)$), then $A$ is the Fourier matrix and its inverse is simply the conjugate of $A$, but what happens if $a$ is not a root of unity?

Comment: The need for  formal inverse is due to the fact that this matrix $A$ gets very ill-conditioned as soon as $|a| \neq 1$. Hence numerical solving fails for large $N$, even if using the Fourier matrix as a preconditioner.

Comment: It may help to know that this is an instance of a [Vandermonde matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)

Comment: Yes, indeed. It is a very particular case of Vandermonde matrix for which there are tools via the Lagrange basis polynomials, but those tools are totally unworkable here (I need working with values of N between 1000 and 100.000). So I am wondering if the fact that this matrix is a very specific Vandermonde matrix may lead to a more simple formal inverse.